# Criss Cross duplicates searching for phone numbers

Tags: mysql, duplicate-data

I need to list all duplicate phone numbers in the contacts table.

There are 2 fields for phone number : phone_mobile and phone_work

**Contacts Table:**

```
id | first_name | last_name | phone_mobile | phone_work

1  | Raghu       | Nath     | 8756123454   | 9976543120
2  | Sheryl      | John     | 9898765431   | 8765412901    
3  | Joseph      | Ovett    | 8756123454   | 0876451230    
4  | Sheryl      | John     | 9976543120   | NULL
```

I have the query to find duplicates on single column, e.g. I want to get duplicates on phone_mobile

SQL :

```
SELECT contacts.id, 
       CONCAT(contacts.first_name," ",contacts.last_name) as full_name, 
       contacts.phone_mobile, contacts.phone_work 
FROM contacts 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT first_name, phone_mobile, phone_work, count(*) as rows 
   FROM `contacts` 
   WHERE deleted = 0 
   GROUP BY phone_mobile 
   HAVING count(rows) > 1
) as p 
WHERE contacts.deleted=0 AND p.`phone_mobile` = contacts.`phone_mobile` AND contacts.`phone_mobile` != '' 
ORDER BY contacts.date_entered DESC, contacts.first_name, contacts.last_name;
```

And this returns below output : Return all duplicates on phone_mobile field.

```
id | first_name | last_name | phone_mobile | phone_work

1  | Raghu       | Nath     | 8756123454   | 9976543120
3  | Joseph      | Ovett    | 8756123454   | 0876451230
```

But if I want to find duplicates on both phone_mobile and phone_work in a single query how should I modify my query?

My output should become : Here number 9976543120 is in phone_work of id 1 and in phone_mobile of id 4

```
id | first_name | last_name | phone_mobile | phone_work

1  | Raghu       | Nath     | 8756123454   | 9976543120
3  | Joseph      | Ovett    | 8756123454   | 0876451230    
4  | Sheryl      | John     | 9976543120   | NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may first UNION data from both `phone_mobile` and `mobile_work` columns. Then find duplicates in that data. After that you may JOIN the duplicate numbers with the original `contacts` table to get your desired results, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT contacts.* FROM contacts
JOIN (
  SELECT phone FROM (
    SELECT phone_mobile AS phone FROM contacts
    UNION ALL
    SELECT phone_work AS phone FROM contacts
  ) t1
  GROUP BY phone
  HAVING count(phone) > 1
) t2
ON (contacts.phone_mobile = t2.phone OR contacts.phone_work = t2.phone)
```

Demo on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bf58/8

Here the inner most table `t1` does the UNION, then `t2` gets you duplicates, and then the outermost JOIN gives you contacts having same phone numbers (either in phone_mobile column or phone_work column).